# Longtable integration Stata

Tags: tables, environments, longtable, statistics

As far as I am aware, the available commands that produce LaTeX-formatted tables of stored estimates using Stata, will only produce tables using either the `table` or `tabular` environments. Do any other alternative commands exists that for given output, produces a table using the `longtable` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, there was an update of the estout package in stata including a longtable option.

source: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-02/msg00688.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077)